# Funcion objeto de personas

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando con javaScript y tengo la siguiente funcion,estoy un poco revuelta, podrian ayudarme. Si tiene la propiedad "invitado" y, además, tiene las propiedades "nombre" y "apellido", tomar esos valores y retorna:"Lionel Messi, un gusto tenerlo nuevamente! Bienvenido".

Si tiene la propiedad "invitado" y solo tiene la propiedad "apellido", retornar:"Bienvenido Sr. Messi".

Si tiene la propiedad "invitado" y solo tiene la propiedad "nombre", retornar:"Hola Lionel, tu mesa está lista".

En caso de que no tenga la propiedad "invitado" retornar:"Disculpe señor, no está invitado a la fiesta".

```js
// La funcion recibe un objeto "persona".
// de la forma: 
// {
//  nombre: 'Lionel
//  apellido: 'Messi',
//  invitado: true
//  }
// Si tiene la propiedad "invitado" y, además, tiene las propiedades "nombre" y "apellido", tomar esos valores y retorna:
// "Lionel Messi, un gusto tenerlo nuevamente! Bienvenido".
// Si tiene la propiedad "invitado" y solo tiene la propiedad "apellido", retornar:
// "Bienvenido Sr. Messi".
// Si tiene la propiedad "invitado" y solo tiene la propiedad "nombre", retornar:
// "Hola Lionel, tu mesa está lista".
// En caso de que no tenga la propiedad "invitado" retornar:
// "Disculpe señor, no está invitado a la fiesta".



  

   const personas = [
    {
        nombre: 'Toni',
        apellido: 'Tralice',
        invitado: true
    },
    {
        apellido: 'Rodriguez',
        invitado: true
    },
    {
        nombre: 'Matias',
        invitado: true
    },
    {
        nombre: 'Leandro',
        apellido: 'Dominguez'
    }
];


    let newObject= () >= {
    return personas.reduce(newObject.personas) >= {
        if (personas.invitado) {
         newObject.invitado(personas)
         retur newObject
        }else{
          newObject.noInvitado.push(personas)
        }
        return newObject
    }, {invitado:[], noInvitado:[]}

    }
};
    console.log(newObject())
```

Comment: Bienvenida! Consulta ¿Cuál es la pregunta concreta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te dejo un Script Funcional con lo que colocas en tu enunciado:

```js
const personas = [
    {
        nombre: 'Toni',
        apellido: 'Tralice',
        invitado: true
    },
    {
        apellido: 'Rodriguez',
        invitado: true
    },
    {
        nombre: 'Matias',
        invitado: true
    },
    {
        nombre: 'Leandro',
        apellido: 'Dominguez'
    }
];

function bienvenidoSr(persona)
{

for (var i = 0; i < persona.length; i++) {
if(persona[i]["nombre"]!=undefined && persona[i]["apellido"]!=undefined && persona[i]["invitado"]==true)
      {
        console.log(persona[i]["nombre"]+" "+persona[i]["apellido"]+" un gusto tenerlo nuevamente! Bienvenido");
      }
      if(persona[i]["apellido"]!=undefined && persona[i]["invitado"]==true && persona[i]["nombre"]==undefined)
      {
        console.log("Bienvenido Sr. "+persona[i]["apellido"]);
      }
      if(persona[i]["nombre"]!=undefined && persona[i]["invitado"]==true)
      {
      console.log("Hola "+persona[i]["nombre"]+", tu mesa está lista");
      
      }
      if(persona[i]["invitado"]!=true)
      {
      console.log("Disculpe señor, no está invitado a la fiesta");
      }
} 
   
}

bienvenidoSr(personas);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!